# Can't connect to port 993 for a specific domain only

Tags: imap

I have a strange issue on a Mac where port 993 is blocked for one site only. In Terminal I can type:

```
nc -vz imap.gmail.com 993
```

and I get a succeeded message BUT

```
nc -vz uk2.siteground.eu 993 fails and times out, yet

nc -vz uk2.siteground.eu 443 AND
nc -vz uk2.siteground.eu 465
```

Always succeed, so it's just one Port on that site.  All works fine from other devices.

What has happened to my Mac, and how do I remove this block?

Comment: How can you be certain that the *site* doesn’t have that port blocked?

Comment: I get `Connection to uk2.siteground.eu port 993 [tcp/imaps] succeeded!` so the service seems to up and running on the remote site. How is your network configuration *between* the Mac and the remote site?

Comment: Also, if the port was being blocked, the connection would be “refused.”  The fact that it’s timing out means it’s not responding and `nc` is just giving up.  Does that site have a firewall that will ignore requests from IPs that make too many requests within a certain time period?